# How to route particular IP via one of the OpenVPN clients

Tags: iptables, routing, openvpn

I have several fedora servers being gateways for local networks and are connected via tunnels:

- **server A** running OpenVPN server  with eth0 192.168.1.1/24 tun0 192.168.94.1 and eth1 1.1.1.1
- **server B** running OpenVPN  with eth0 192.168.20.1/24 tun0 192.168.94.20 and eth1 2.2.2.2
- **server C** running OpenVPN  with eth0 192.168.30.1/24 tun0 192.168.94.32 and eth1 3.3.3.3

Each server managing own /24 network clients and letting them use internet via local eth1 pub IP. and all local /24 networks see each other with no problem (`iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.0.0/16 -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT`) and currently NAT do MASQ only for each local /24 network.

Now I would like my client in network A 192.168.1.101 to access public IP 4.4.4.4 via **Server B**.  I've tried adding route on **Server A**

```
ip ro add 4.4.4.4 via 192.168.20.1
ip ro add 4.4.4.4 via 192.168.94.8
ip ro add 4.4.4.4 via 192.168.94.9
ip ro add 4.4.4.4 via 192.168.94.10  #(this is IP shown in ifconfig on SERVER B)
echo "200 custom"| tee -a /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
ip rule add to 4.4.4.4 lookup custom
ip ro add 4.4.4.4 via 192.168.20.1 tables custom
ip ro add 4.4.4.4 via 192.168.94.8 dev tun0 table custom
ip ro add 4.4.4.4 via 192.168.94.9 table custom
ip ro add 4.4.4.4 via 192.168.94.10 table custom  #(this is IP shown in ifconfig on SERVER B)
```

But I always get `Error: Nexthop has invalid gateway.` even though I can ping OK 192.168.20.1 or 192.168.94.10.  What am I doing wrong?

I presume it should be possible to reroute particular local client via different gateway.

For example locally I can easily do it as **Server A** has eth2 with 192.168.2.2 and I can reroute particular public IP through another **server D** with 192.168.2.1 on the same location (`ip ro add 5.5.5.5 via 192.168.2.1`) and I get no error and works fine, also rerouting particular client in 192.168.1.x to use **Gateway D**

Extra output as requested by comments on main server.  Others have analogus.

```
#ip -br link
lo               UNKNOWN        00:00:00:00:00:00 <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> 
eth1             UNKNOWN        00:11:22:33:44:55 <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
eth0             UP             55:44:33:22:11:00 <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> 
tun0             UNKNOWN        <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> 

#ip -br addr
lo               UNKNOWN        127.0.0.1/8 ::1/128
eth1             UNKNOWN        1.1.1.1/23 fedb::1233:feef:fedc:1234/64 
eth0             UP             192.168.1.1/24 fedc::1234:cdef:fedc:bbbb/64 
tun0             UNKNOWN        192.168.94.1 peer 192.168.94.2/32 fe80::ddce:16ea:1c30:809a/64
```

routing on main server

```
#ip ro ls
default via 1.1.0.1 dev eth1 
1.1.0.0/23 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 1.1.1.1 metric 101 
192.168.0.0/16 via 192.168.94.2 dev tun0 
192.168.1.0/24 dev en2 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.1 metric 100 
192.168.94.0/24 via 192.168.94.2 dev tun0 
192.168.94.2 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.94.1
```

Comment: doesn't really change your question, but "Class C" is a term that's obsolete since [CIDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing), 1993. (you just mean a "/24 network", to put it in CIDR notation, so that concept does translate quite well) Wherever you learned something that involves routing and classful IP networks is based on knowledge that's been irrelevant for 30 years. (might give you a hint to look at different learning materials)

Comment: Thanks for clearing up the answer and "Class C" term explanation... Maybe I'm getting older rather than reading old materials now.

Comment: the term you're looking for is "more experienced with a richer background in technology", not "getting older" ;-)

Comment: Can you provide your current setup (before the experiments) with `ip -br link; ip -br addr; ip route`, `iptables-save -c` on each system? And also `ip -d link show dev tun0 |grep -Po 'type \w+'` (just to know if it's a tun or a tap, for some details). Currently I can just tell that `ip rule add to 4.4.4.4 lookup custom` is useless, that's already what are doing usual route entries. It might be a chore to then obfuscate the results, but all the tiny missing details add to the difficulty of receiving help.

Comment: Hey @A.B, that is a lot of output for the comments, or even to edit the post.  All servers are using tun dev for tunneling.  I'll update my question with some outputs